# what is a population-based survey experiment?

Tags: experiment-design, survey

What is the core of population-based survey experiment method?

Especially on issues as follow:

1. manipulation
2. control
3. random assignment

Is there any distinctive element contained in the method which makes it special?

Comment: Can you tell us why you want to know this? You can write books on such a topic, e.g. Katrin Auspurg and Thomas Hinz (2015) *Factorial Survey Experiments*. Thousand Oaks: Sage. Writing book length answers is not what we want to do and not what you want to read. So we need to narrow the question down to something more managable, Knowing why you want to know something often helps a lot with that.

Comment: @MaartenBuis I couldn't afford to buy such a book, so I sifted through some materials about the topic, but couldn't get the core. I'm afraid I gave such a broad question, but all I wanted is a summarize of the most distinctive character that represents the method. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That book is not as expensive as most textbooks ($22 new and 16.34 used on Amazon). But I realize that it is possible that is still too expensive. In that case: that is what libraries are for.

Comment: We need to know what you want to know in order to give you a summary that is helpful to you. So the question remains: why do you want to know this?

Comment: @MaartenBuis sometimes before go to the library or buy the book, it's a way more clever to put a simple question online and acquire an instant information to be prepared. If you are have no intention on giving relevant information, then please stop those uncomfortable tone.

Comment: I am trying to find out what you want to know in order to give an answer that is helpful to you. If you find that uncomfortable than I appologize.

Comment: @MaartenBuis thanks for the book you recommended. I'll go over it soon.